# None of my sources are being found

Tags: android, eclipse

Okay, so I'm trying to get my app to work on my phone to see if it works. I'm noticing that the button that I want to make a phone call is not doing anything. Here's the code:

```
public boolean onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View callButton2 = null;
callButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
         try {
             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
             String p = "tel:" + getString(R.string.phoneNumber);
             i.setData(Uri.parse(p));
             startActivity(i);
         } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
             Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);}
         finally{}
     }
```

I put the permission in the Manifest file and it still doesn't work. So I was investigating and found out that literally none of my sources are being found. Will this severely disfigure my app, or does it not matter? Also, how do I get them back?

Comment: waiting for more code to just provide the right answer as only moving this line will not solve NPE

Answer (score 2):

From where you called this function "onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState)"

```
public boolean onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 View callButton2 = null;
 callButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // <---
```

this line will throw NPE error.

So when your app is running, we are not getting call on this function `public boolean onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Comment: So are you saying move this to onCreate?

Comment: that depends on code ? need complete activity to suggest right answer

Comment: How people can be so irresponsible just  down-voted with out having reason

Comment: I downvoted it literally a few minutes ago because it is formatted horribly and grammatically makes no sense.  You are right with the NPE and I'm trying to upvote it again, but it won't work.  No need to panic.

Comment: @ Atlos : I was not expecting upvote ..I was expecting reason ...  for me problem resolution important than making perfect in English grammar

Comment: If you have very good English grammar rather than just downvoted edit the answer, that misguided the person .......

Comment: Jeez, if you guys don't like the formatting errors or grammatical issues, then edit it if you can.

Comment: Dude... it took me <10 minutes to add a comment.  Relax.  Yawus edited your post and now it is readable so I un-downvoted it.  An answer is not helpful if nobody can read it.

Comment: @user1287195 waiting for more code to just provide the right answer as only moving this line will not solve NPE

Comment: @Atlos check http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11233192/revisions it was not in that worst condition ever .........

Answer (score 1):

The method `onStart()` should be

```
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    ...
}
```

Because the method is not correct, Android won't call it at all during the `Activity Lifecycle`.  Try fixing that and then putting your `OnClickListener` inside.

edit: Also, it is good practice to initialize your `Views` in `onCreate()` rather than `onStart()`.

Like Dheeresh Singh said, you will also crash with a `NullPointerException` because you are assigning your `Button` to be null.  You first need to assign it to a `Button` in your layout by calling `findViewById()` or by creating it in code.  Right now you are essentially calling `null.setOnClickListener()` which does not make any sense.

Comment: The only reason I'm stating null is because the Quick Fix is telling me that the button may not have been initialized. Do I just ignore it?

Comment: No, you need to initialize the Button.  Add the Button to the layout XML and then use something like `Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.<yourbuttonid>);`